# how to install driver for intel wireless-AC 3168 in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I recently installed ubuntu 16.04 and i have hard time finding wifi driver I dont see any wifi driver in additional settings and i downloaded wifi driver from intel website it is in tar format but i dont know how to install it.I also moved it to lib/firmware folder and still it doesn't work.Help please

Comment: It was not a good idea to install from the 16.04 ISO. If you installed 16.04.2, or 3, it would have worked without any additional effort.

Comment: i just did what was there from the link still no use when i typed rfkill list all it shows only bluetooth with soft blocked:yes my version is 16.04.3

Comment: Thanks for your support i rebooted my system then now its detecting wifi Thanks to you